# Why is the Enemy's Sprite Flipping When it Sees the Player?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, ai

So I have a method that flips an enemies sprite if depending on what direction they're moving. I also have a script that determines if it can see the player. Currently, the enemy sprite faces the correct direction when moving, but as soon as it sees the player, it flips around away from the player. Why is this happening?

Sorry in advance for all of the code...

```
 [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
 [RequireComponent(typeof(Seeker))]

 public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour {

 // What to chase
 public Transform target;

 // How many times each second we will update our path
 public float updateRate = 2f;

 // Caching
 private Seeker seeker;
 private Rigidbody2D rb;

 // The calculated path
 public Path path;

 // The AI's speed per second
 public float speed = 300f;
 public ForceMode2D fMode;

 [HideInInspector]
 public bool pathIsEnded = false;

 // The max distance from the AI to a waypoint for it to continue to the next waypoint
 public float nextWaypointDistance = 3f;

 // The waypoint we are currently moving towards
 private int currentWaypoint = 0;

 private bool searchingForPlayer = false;

 public bool facingRight = true;

 public bool stillSearching = false;

 float horizontalVelocity;

 float timer = 0f;

 float continueSearchingTime = 5f;

 Vector3 enemyLocation;

 Player player;
 EnemySenses enemySenses;

 void Start()
 {
     player = Player.instance;
     enemySenses = EnemySenses.instance;

     enemyLocation = transform.localScale;

     seeker = GetComponent<Seeker>();
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

     if (target == null)
     {
         if (!searchingForPlayer)
         {
             searchingForPlayer = true;
             StartCoroutine(SearchForPlayer());
         }
         return;
     }

     // Start a new path to the target position, return the result to the OnPathComplete method
     seeker.StartPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathComplete);

     StartCoroutine(UpdatePath());
 }

 void Update()
 {
     Flip();
 }

 void FixedUpdate()
 {

     if (target != null && player.isDead == true || target != null && enemySenses.CanPlayerBeSeen() == false && stillSearching == false)
     {
         searchingForPlayer = false;
         return;
     }
     else if (target != null && stillSearching == true && enemySenses.CanPlayerBeSeen() == false)
     {
         if (!searchingForPlayer)
         {
             searchingForPlayer = true;
             StartCoroutine(SearchForPlayer());
         }
     }
     else if (target == null)
     {
         if (!searchingForPlayer)
         {
             searchingForPlayer = true;
             StartCoroutine(SearchForPlayer());
         }
         return;
     }

     if (path == null)
         return;

     if (currentWaypoint >= path.vectorPath.Count)
     {
         if (pathIsEnded)
             return;

         // Debug.Log("End of path reached.");
         pathIsEnded = true;
         return;
     }

     pathIsEnded = false;

     // Direction to the next waypoint
     Vector3 dir = (path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint] - transform.position).normalized;
     dir *= speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

     // Move the AI
     rb.AddForce(dir, fMode);

     float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]);
     if (dist < nextWaypointDistance)
     {
         currentWaypoint++;
         return;
     }
 }

 void LateUpdate()
 {

 }

 void Flip()
 {
     horizontalVelocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x;

     if (facingRight == true && horizontalVelocity < 0) // Facing right and moving left
     {
         enemyLocation.x *= -1;
         transform.localScale = enemyLocation;
         facingRight = false;
     }
     else if (facingRight == false && horizontalVelocity > 0) // Facing left and moving right
     {
         enemyLocation.x *= -1;
         transform.localScale = enemyLocation;
         facingRight = true;
     }
 }

 IEnumerator SearchForPlayer()
 {
     GameObject searchResult = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
     if (searchResult == null)
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
         StartCoroutine(SearchForPlayer());
     }
     else if (player.isDead == false)
     {
         target = searchResult.transform;
         searchingForPlayer = false;
         StartCoroutine(UpdatePath());
         yield return false;
     }
 }

 IEnumerator UpdatePath()
 {
     if (target == null)
     {
         if (!searchingForPlayer)
         {
             searchingForPlayer = true;
             StartCoroutine(SearchForPlayer());
         }
         yield return false;
     }

     // Start a new path to the target position, return the result to the OnPathComplete method
     seeker.StartPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathComplete);

     yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / updateRate);
     StartCoroutine(UpdatePath());
 }

 public void OnPathComplete (Path p)
 {
     // Debug.Log("We got a path. Did it have an error? " + p.error);
     if (!p.error)
     {
         path = p;
         currentWaypoint = 0;
     }
 }

 IEnumerator OnTriggerExit2D()
 {
     stillSearching = true;

     while (timer < continueSearchingTime)
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
         timer++;
         Debug.Log("Timer: " + timer);
     }

     if (timer > continueSearchingTime)
     {
         stillSearching = false;
     }
 }

 void OnTriggerEnter2D()
 {
     timer = 0;
     stillSearching = false;
 }
```

Comment: Your problem is likely do with using the localScale to flip the sprite, try using `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true / false;` and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: flipX only affects the sprite though. I have colliders and such that wouldn't flip by using flipX